# Entered weird mode, tab switch between "Edit" and "Edit Strokes"

Tags: edit-mode

[image]

I did *something* I am not sure, but now Tab key switch between "Edit" and "Edit Strokes" mode without going out to the object mode. When I click the mode it says "Object Mode" but that's actually an edit mode. Also, all the armatures displayed in X-Ray are all gone. And edit mode does not show editable vertexes like it should be.

In this Edit Mode I can only try to right click around the area that I remembered there is an armature, the yellow name at bottom left would change accordingly without any other visual indication. I can press G to grab the invisible armature and move them. (I know this because it is showing Dx Dy Dz text)

One way I found to exit from this state is to load other workspace preset. But if I come back to this preset it still stuck in this state. What exactly is this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out. I was in [Local View mode](http://blender-manual-i18n.readthedocs.io/ja/latest/getting_started/basics/navigating/global_or_local_view.html). I didn't notice all the layer buttons are gone until I want to use it. In local view mode armature does not show.

I have no idea how I got in there because I have no numpad and I could not press numpad / to enter it, but luckily View > View Global/Local solve this.

Answer (score 1):

this link might help

https://docs.blender.org/manual/de/dev/interface/grease_pencil/stroke_edit.html

if you want to get out of stroke edit mode try pressing d-tab